# why the command whoami in hbase shell can't obtain group information?

Tags: active-directory, hbase, cloudera-cdh

I have a `cdh hadoop cluster`, which use active directory for `authentication` and `authourization`. When I use `hbase` shell, the client can't get group mapping information from hdfs. As I have understand, `hbase` get group mapping information from `hdfs`, so I tried `hdfs` group command and it returns the right group information in the AD. Could someone tell me where is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add  ldap password in the file '/etc/hbase/conf.cloudera.hbase/core-site.xml' :

```
<property>
<name>hadoop.security.group.mapping.ldap.bind.password</name>
<value>insert_password_here</value>
</property>
```

But I wonder why CDH does not config it right?